# Check keyboard input if empty OR not "Y" OR not "X"

Tags: java, input, while-loop

I want to check my input it's empty or not "Y" or not "X"

```
while (weiterInput.isEmpty() || !weiterInput.equals("X") || !weiterInput.equals("Y")) {..}
```

If I input "X" or "Y" it doesn't exit the loop like it's supposed to.

Comment: `&&`, not `||`. You have the wrong operator. And `!isEmpty`

Comment: if you enter X or Y, the other negative condition will still be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop will never terminate, since `weiterInput` will never be equal to both "X" and "Y", so either `!weiterInput.equals("X")` or `!weiterInput.equals("Y")` will always by `true`.

You need:

```
while (weiterInput.isEmpty() ||
      (!weiterInput.equals("X") && !weiterInput.equals("Y"))) {            

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is just this :

```
while (!weiterInput.matches("[XY]?")){...}
```

---

Edit :

> I also can test for lowercase and other variants (yes, YES, Yes, y, Y) with less coding

In this case just change the regex to be :

```
if (!weiterInput.matches("(?i)(yes|y)?")){
```

Note that `(?i)` will match case insensitive, so don't worry about YES, Yes, Y..

Comment: nice, so because its a yes or nor question i also can test for lowercase and other variants (yes, YES, Yes, y, Y) with less coding

Comment: @SteffenBauer In this case you can just use `if (!weiterInput.matches("(?i)(yes|y)?")){`

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up your logic.

If you wanted to check if it is empty or equal to X or equal to Y, it would be

```
(weiterInput.isEmpty() || weiterInput.equals("X") || weiterInput.equals("Y"))
```

If you want the *opposite* of that, just negate the whole expression

```
(!(weiterInput.isEmpty() || weiterInput.equals("X") || weiterInput.equals("Y")))
```